# How to delete values in two dimensional array (PHP)?

Tags: php

I have an array which looks like

```
        $cclArray[0]['url']='test.html';
        $cclArray[0]['entity_id']=9;
        $cclArray[1]['url']='test1.html';
        $cclArray[1]['entity_id']=10;
        $cclArray[2]['url']='test2.html';
        $cclArray[2]['entity_id']=11;
```

if i would like to remove a specific array, for example if i want to delete the array element with `'url'='test1.html'` .. how do i do it?

Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ( $cclArray as $k => $array ) {
    if ( $array['url'] == 'test1.html' ) {
        unset($cclArray[$k]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP >5.3 you can do it simply like this:

```
$cclArray = array_filter($cclArray, function ($var) {
    return $var['url'] != 'test1.html';
});
```

- [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)
- [Anonymous functions in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: And with PHP < 5.3 you could do the same using `create_function()`.

Answer (score 1):

if you make your array this way

```
    $cclArray['test.html'] = 9;
    $cclArray['test1.html'] = 10;
    $cclArray['test2.html'] = 11;
```

it will be possible to delete with just

```
$url = 'test.html';
unset($cclArray[$url]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($cclArray as $key=>$val){
  if($val['url'] == 'test1.html'){
   unset($cclArray[$key]);
  }
}
```

I think this is it.

Comment: `unset($val[$key])` - key is a numeric value of keys in `$cclArray` (0, 1, 2). You are unseting right now `$val[0]` - not `$cclArray[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($cclArray);$i++)
  if($cclArray[$i]['url']=='test.html') unset($cclArray[$i]['url'])
```

Comment: Please don't give examples with `count()` in a `for` condition.

Comment: why not? you think, right part of this condition is being calculated on each iteration?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I'm always happy to refresh my knowledge. http://www.codeforest.net/php-mythbusters-count-inside-for-loop-is-slow

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0; $i<count($cclArray); $i++){
    if('test1.html' === $cclArray[$i]['url']){
        array_splice($cclArray, $i, 1);
    }
}
```

This is better but remember that unset() does not remove actual element it just sets it to null. If you want it to be complete gone, then after the unset() you should also do this: $cclArray = array_filter($cclArray);

Or you can do this in order to complete remove the array element instead of just unsetting it

```
for($i=0; $i<count($cclArray); $i++){
if('test1.html' === $cclArray[$i]['url']){
array_splice($cclArray, $i, 1);
}
```

}

Comment: Not sure you you mean. Inside the foreach look the $k is the value of $key of main array and $array is value of your nested array.

Comment: Have you tried it? I did, and my solution with array_splice worked as expected. Try it youself - it does completely remove the actual element fro array not from a copy.

Comment: Please don't give examples with `count()` in a `for` condition.